# How to increase header size in Grails 4/tomcat (spring-boot)?

Tags: spring-boot, grails, http-headers

In Grails how can you increase the response header size?

We are using Grails 4. This is basically Spring boot. It uses an embedded Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to application.yml with

```
server:
    max-http-header-size: 20000
```

Also check if you have any additional info in tokens, which is not needed.

Comment: @SnoopyNaybor if this worked you can accept the answer so in the future you will get better chances